# Algorithm for finding shortest directed odd circuit in a digraph

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to find an algorithm for finding shortest directed odd circuit in a digraph. I would use breadth-first-search, but I don't know how to find odd cycles. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an undirected graph has an odd length cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146620/how-to-check-if-an-undirected-graph-has-an-odd-length-cycle)

Comment: @ravenspoint That is for undirected graphs. I am asking about directed graphs.

Comment: What difference does being directed or not make?  Have you actually tried to apply one of the algorithms offered in the answered to that question?

Comment: @ravenspoint If I find a shortest cycle in a directed graph, what use is that if the cycle is not directed?